# MySQL backup using cmd

Tags: windows-7, mysql, mysqldump

When I try to backup my DB using command prompt command

```
mysqldump -u root -p db_name > path to store
```

It prompts

**Enter password:**

And within seconds before I enter my password, it redirects back to CMD.
Also a file is created in the location mentioned and it contains nothing.

But when I try giving the password in the command itself, it generates proper dump file. Some please tell what is the reason.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming your dump is dumping the "training" database that does not exist.  You need to format your command to reference the "training customers" database.

**You need to add quotes around your database name.**

A common thing to do for naming things with spaces (white space) in databases is to never include white space, and eliminate the white space with a name like "trainingcustomers" or replacing the space with an underscore (training_customers).  Hyphens are less common to fill white space but a tertiary choice.

Answer (score 0):

I can only think of some pre-configuration, which is picked up by mysqldump (like default user and pass), which is wrong, because mysqldump exits without telling the reason. Try to browse through the mysql config files for it, also check mysql log for any messages. Maybe you have system variable set, like PASSWORD, which is then picked up by mysqldump, when password after -p is not given.